# What determines whether heroes trust each other?

Tags: dungeon-of-the-endless

The [Got Your Back](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Got_Your_Back) feat gives the following bonus:

> +10% Defense when near group members they trust.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to determine which heroes trust which other heroes or how trust might be gained.

How does trust work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to be based on [Factions](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Heroes#Factions).

> Heroes belong to one of three factions: Crew, Prisoners and Natives.
>
> Crew have medium recruitment costs and high leveling cost. They all
>   have the [Got Your Back](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Got_Your_Back) passive skill.
>
> Prisoners have high recruitment costs and medium leveling costs. They
>   all have the [Pack of Dogs](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Pack_of_Dogs) passive skill. After level 10 their Defense
>   no longer increases when leveling up.
>
> Natives have the lowest recruitment and leveling costs but are weaker
>   at low levels. They have no common skill.

As a memo:

> Got Your Back: +10% Defense when near group members they trust.

Heroes that have it:

- [Nurse Deena Ratchet](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Nurse_Deena_Ratchet)
- [Elise Ness](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Elise_Ness)
- [Ken Massoqui](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Ken_Massoqui)
- [Warden Mormish](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Warden_Mormish)
- [Chef Nanor](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Chef_Nanor)
- [Sara Numas](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Sara_Numas)

> Pack of Dogs: (Self) Attack power +6% when their mates are nearby (ie other heroes from the prisoner faction)

Heroes that have it:

- [Golgy Phurtiver](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Golgy_Phurtiver)
- [Gork "Butcher" Koroser](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Gork_%22Butcher%22_Koroser)
- [Max O'Kane](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Max_O%27Kane)
- [Opbot DV8](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Opbot_DV8)
- [Rakya Pulmoni](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Rakya_Pulmoni)
- [Troe Pekenyo](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Troe_Pekenyo)
- [Josh 'Ntello](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Josh_%27Ntello)

Which leaves us with the following as Natives:

- [Hikensha](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Hikensha)
- [Lady Joleri Tulak](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Lady_Joleri_Tulak)
- [Mizi Kurtiz](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Mizi_Kurtiz)
- [Skroig](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Skroig)
- [Kreyang](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Kreyang)
- [Ayairi Whairydd](http://dungeon-of-the-endless.wikia.com/wiki/Ayairi_Whairydd)